# Bootstrap color on text-white class ignored

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I don't have code to show, but I wondered if anyone has come across this problem.

I have a link:

```
<a href="..." class="btn btn-primary text-white">...</a>
```

The text shows up as white, however when the link is active/hover/visited, it's the default purple.

As a test, I've tried adding this right above the link, but it doesn't work:

```
<style>
  .text-white a:hover,
  .text-white a:active,
  .text-white a:visited
  {
    color: white;
  }
</style>
```

**Working Example:**

```css
.text-white a:hover,
.text-white a:active,
.text-white a:visited
{
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary text-white">A Link</a>
```

Comment: What version of bootstrap you are using?

Comment: I have added a `stack-snippet` where your code is working, can you update it to show the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You named your class `.text-white` and in the css you wrote: `.text-color`. The classnames should be equal.

Comment: Fixed post, but that wasn't the issue.